# Can not check out SVN project with error working copy is too old

Tags: macos, svn, project, svn-checkout

I try to check out the repo to a new computer but Smart SVN on mac os x claims that working copy format of ~/ProjectPath is too old '0'.I tried everththing that i found on the web.I upgraded svn to 1.7.6 and i also downloaded the lastest version of smart SVN but it really did  not help.

svn upgrade says the following

```
svn: E155019: Can't upgrade '/Users/ilker/Desktop/CallingCard_v2.0' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory
```

and svn cleanup says

```
svn: E200030: sqlite: no such table: wcroot
```

the only difference that i have on this machine is that i have mac os x 10.6.8 while other clients have at least 10.7.I think but it should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `svn checkout` command to get a new working copy instead of trying to `svn upgrade` your current one ?

Comment: yes of course i do not have the project at all.i get vn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file. when i try to checkout

Comment: Can you tell what is the complete error message? Are you sure you use the correct connection parameters?

Comment: i can browse through the repository so the parameters should be ok.In smart svn it first says invalid parameter and fails to check out then it says "None of the project root directories seems to be under Subversion controlWhat do you want to do? Details:E155021:Working copy format of '/Users/pathtoProjectDir is too old '0' "

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the slightly different situation that resulted in the same error. 
I made checkout on a server that had almost 0% space free. The checkout downloaded the parent directory from SVN but not the content. When I freed disk space and made check out the issue was still there. 
When I deleted the parent directory and made checkout again the issue disappeared.
So you may try deleting the checked out content and checkout again.